# Application crashes on simulator after update Monterey

Tags: xcode, macos, ios-simulator

I updated my mac Big Sur to Monterey Beta.
After update, my application (installed before) not opens on iPhone Simulator (crashes immediately). And on xcode lots of errors appears, can't build.

Simulator crash report:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4341362688
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      mapped file                 102c3f000-103ce7000    [ 16.7M] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...t_id=ca4c8d93
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler [15816]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:



Thread 0 Crashed:
0   ???                                 0x7ff7ffd02bd8 ???
1   <translation info unavailable>         0x1067fbe5c ???
2   dyld                                   0x2068aa88f dyld4::prepareSim(dyld4::RuntimeState&, char const*) + 890
3   dyld                                   0x2068a96b5 dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*) + 244
4   dyld                                   0x2068a94b4 start + 388
5   dyld                                   0x2068a4000 ???

Thread 1:: com.apple.rosetta.exceptionserver
0   ???                                 0x7ff7ffcef320 ???
1   ???                                 0x7ff7ffd081a0 ???


Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x000000010e852af8  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000001
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x000000010eee6000
   r8: 0xbae6d4fe37da0005   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x000000010eee6000  r11: 0x000000010ed12010
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x000000010ed12060  r14: 0x0000000206918080  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: <unavailable>       rfl: 0x0000000000000283
 tmp0: 0x00000001067e9c64 tmp1: 0x00000001067e8f8c tmp2: 0x00000002068c2ca3


Binary Images:
               0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? (*) <00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000> ???
       0x2068a4000 -        0x20690bfff dyld (*) <4e207376-cc5d-3986-a0bd-4d09f4217e68> /usr/lib/dyld
```

Comment: Same here on M1